# Migrate to php55 on GAE using mysqli

Tags: php, google-app-engine, mysqli, unix-socket

We're migrating an existing project from php54 to php55 on Google App Engine, and we getting an error in our App Engine Launcher with mysqli that does not occur when running in the standard php runtime.

Using a simple mysqli connect:

```
$connection = new mysqli('user','pass','localhost','mydatabase');
```

Connects just fine in the php runtime, but in the php55 runtime, we get the following error:

> Unable to find the socket transport "unix" - did you forget to enable
>   it when you configured PHP?

Is mysqli still supported in the php55 runtime? If so, what do we need to change to get this working?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue of SDK 1.9.18. Please update to 1.9.19 and the error should go away.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But we're running 1.9.19 (1.9.19.229) and the problem is still occurring.

Comment: You're right. Looks like the fix didn't make it into 1.9.19. For now, you can change "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" to fix the issue. This will force the mysqli extension to use tcp connection instead of unix socket.

Comment: OK, Thanks. We'll give this a try and mark this as the answer if it works.